# Transfer a trac database from one desktop to another

Tags: trac

I'm using `Trac 0.12.2` that came as a part of *Bitnami Trac Stac*.

I am very new to Trac & just started with Trac, working with a local repository on a desktop a few weeks ago & created some issues. Now I wanted to transfer the all those issues onto my new Trac installation on another desktop. So I simply tried replacing the empty(*I believed*) database folder of new installation with my old Trac DB folder.

Specifically this folder:

```
C:\BitNamiTracStack\repository\db\
```

When I tried doing so, the `admin` tab on the trac interface disappeared.

Also I got a message:

```
   Warning: Can't synchronize with repository "(default)" (The repository directory has changed, you should resynchronize the repository with: trac-admin $ENV repository resync '(default)'). Look in the Trac log for more information.
```

How do I successfully transfer my issues from one desktop to another ?

Comment: Please explain in more detail, what you did. I consider replacing a Trac db not exactly an usual procedure. You'll have a backup copy, if you mess with your working Trac install that way, haven’t you? What is 'old' and 'new' referring to in this context? Far to few information by now on problem (btw. what Trac version(s) involved?) to be able to give you any useful hint. Edit/extend your question, please.

Comment: @hasienda: Updated my question to include more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your installation and find the correct directory called 'Trac environment' as per Remy's advice.

While his answer is the safe road and general advice without doubt, you may still succeed with a less complete transfer, depending on what you already put into the Trac environment in question. Assuming you do use BitNami's default Trac db backend (SQLite) you'll need at least

- the latest db named `trac.db` from the `db` folder
- the configuration file `conf/trac.ini`

If you've worked with attachments to tickets or wiki pages, the *whole directory structure* below `attachements` is needed as well.

Other things might not have been touched by a self-declared "very new" Trac user within the first weeks. Of course a `diff -Nur <path_to_old_dir> <path_to_new_dir> | <your_favorite_editor>` will remind you of anything you may have already forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't copy the database alone, but the complete Trac environment. That's the directory containing the `attachments`, `conf`, `db`, `htdocs`, `log`, `plugins` and `templates` directories. In your case, this seems to be the directory:

```
C:\BitNameTracStack\repository
```

(I'm not familiar with the BitNami stack, but the name "repository" sounds suspect. I hope they don't put the Trac environment below the Subversion repository.)

Comment: As far as my recent install of Trac stack from BitNami tells me, this is **not** the case. They are separate, side-by-side in the same parent directory, by default. However, the path can be customized at install time, so this may vary a lot between local installations.

Comment: there were two folders namely `projects` and `repository`. I found all the folders you mentioned above in *<myproject>* folder inside `Projects`. I just replaced those files/folders with my old installation files/folders but it still doesnt seem to resolve the issue. I didnt touched any files/folder in the `repository` directory

Answer (score 0):

See the [official Trac documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBackup) on backing up a Trac environment and restoring it.  You should be able to use this to migrate your config to another server.